# Issue with sample exercise from "Learn the Bash Shell, 3rd ed." [Newham, Cameron]

Tags: bash

From Ch 2. "Learning the Bash Shell" 3rd edition, 'The fc Command':

> "Remember that fc actually runs the command(s) after you edit them.
> Therefore, the last-named choice can be dangerous. bash will attempt
> to execute all commands in the range you specify when you exit your
> editor. If you have typed in any multi-line constructs (like those we
> will cover in Chapter 5), the results could be even more dangerous.
> Although these might seem like valid ways of generating “instant shell
> programs,” a far better strategy would be to direct the output of fc
> -ln with the same arguments to a file; then edit that file and execute the commands when you’re satisfied with them:
>
> `$ fc -l cp > lastcommands`
>
> `$ vi lastcommands`
>
> `$ source lastcommands`
>
> In this case, the shell will not try to execute the file when you
> leave the editor!"

I did:

> `$ fc -l`

Which gave the output:

> 1   echo test1

> 2   echo test2

> 3   echo test3

> 4   echo test4

So I tried:

> `$ fc -l cp > lastcommands`

But got:

`-bash: fc: history specification out of range`

Wondering why I get that out of range error. The file 'lastcommands' is created but it is empty.

Comment: `fc -l 1 3` should work. `-l` expects a range of history indexes as argument. Run `history`, the numbers to the left are possible arguments to fc

Comment: `fc -l` by itself will ouput up the last 16 in history so I wonder why it doesn't work with the `cp` command. Anyways, your suggestion worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried:
>
> ```
> $ fc -l cp > lastcommands
> ```
>
> But got:
>
> ```
> -bash: fc: history specification out of range
> ```

Reviewing `help fc` (truncated)

```
$ help fc
fc: fc [-e ename] [-lnr] [first] [last]
    Display or execute commands from the history list.

    … FIRST can be a
    string, which means the most recent command beginning with that
    string.
    …
     -l        list lines instead of editing
```

You passed `FIRST` as string `cp`. It appears there is no command in your history beginning with `cp`.

Try it with a unique string that will definitely not be a command in your bash history:

```
fc -l NOTINYOURHISTORY
```

You'll get the same error.